# why can't return NULL be used when the return type is int

Tags: c++

My function has the return type int.I want to return nothing in one case. using return NULL appears to be erroneous. what is to be used instead return NULL?

Comment: How is `NULL` defined in your environment?

Comment: What C++ version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot return *nothing*. You can only do that with pointer types. Even if you get it to compile, it will return `0`, not *nothing*.

Comment: No, even for pointer types you have to return a pointer. It can be zero.

Comment: Yes, that's what the `nullptr` stands for. It's a common convention that a pointer of zero value does not point to anything... or *nothing*.

Comment: Yes, so you're returning a pointer. You're not returning *nothing*. You're returning something that *refers to nothing*.

Comment: @Columbo Technically, you are absolutely right. And you are absolutely not helping if you cannot bring your answer to a level that the asker will understand. even if that means you have to simplify.

Comment: Yes, and you are absolutely not helpful if you confuse the asker by telling him that he can basically omit a `return` statement for functions returning a pointer. Your answer has implications that can easily lead to misunderstandings. :)

Comment: The asker seems 100% aware that he needs a return statement.

Comment: I agree with Columbo that this answer can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11 `NULL` can be either defined as an integral constant expression that evaluates to zero, or `nullptr`. If the latter is the case then your program is ill-formed as `nullptr` cannot be converted to `int`.

`NULL` is an obsolete macro used to express a null pointer constant in an idiomatic way. It doesn't represent an "empty" object. For that, other techniques like `boost::optional` are available.
However, that is most certainly not what you need, so just rethink your design and how to return a value that is outside the normal output range and indicates an empty return value. (E.g. `-1`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function like this:

```
int GetPrice (const char* product)
{
    if (FindProduct (product)) {
        return GetProduct (product)->price;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

this won't do what you expect. Even if NULL is defined to NULL (as is for some older compilers), you will return the numeric value 0, so for people calling your function there will be no way to understand whether a product is free (price is 0) or the product was not found.

In C++, you can solve this for instance by using a reference:

```
bool GetPrice (const char* product, int& price)
{
    if (FindProduct (product)) {
        price = GetProduct (product)->price;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In a future standard, you may achieve what you want by using an `optional` value: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional. You can easily mimic this by returning for instance a struct with a bool indicating whether the value was set.